# What is the difference b/w Oracle Business Rules and IBM ILOG JRules

Tags: oracle, business-rules, jrules

What is the difference b/w Oracle Business Rules and ILOG JRULES

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First point would be that almost all rule engines are identical, except the software stack they integrate into.  Most are Java, which means they work great in Java environments.  However in some cases you may want to integrate into other environments.  I.E. SAP, Oracle, etc.

One big thing I want to see in a rule engine is a solid user interface.  ILOG uses the Eclipse IDE for it's interface, whereas Oracle uses Word/Excel.

Points on UI go to Oracle because every business user in the world is familar with MS Office, which is very simple when you compare it to the Eclipse IDE which is very confusing.

As for integration, I don't know what each vendor offers, but I know they definitely both support Java environments easily.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

IBM ILOG also has an interface for excel called
[WebSphere ILOG Rule Solutions for Office](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/business-rule-management/rule-office/)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your activity, what the business want and on the budget.
And, more importantly on who will author the rules. if it is DEV guys then any will do
If it is Business guys then JRules is the best from far.

JRules is the most mature product with a good developer interface because it is a well integrated plugin for eclipse
Business user (non-technical) interface is fantastic and allows proper human language for rule edition.
Plus you have auto-completion and nice features like that.
One can write a rule in English, one can review it in French or German (depending on which language have been "verbalized").
If you want a powerfull business user interface then give it a try.
JRules also include RSO meaning the ability to edit decision table in Excel and rules in Word.
You can have a plugin for scorecard as well
It is available in COBOL, JAVA and .NET
Uses CEP (Complex Event Processing from version 7.5 which integrates IBM Event something) and the new name of the product is now Decision Manager, if I am correct.

JBoss rules (drools) is a very good approach as well but as it is free the business user interface is not that great. (compared to JRules)
I used it and liked it - as a developper
Best quality/price in my point of you
It uses Eclipse as well

Blaze advizor - if your envirnment is retail, finance or banking.
It uses Eclipse as well (version 7+) but it is a bit crappy because there is almost no auto-completion and is not fully using all the nice feature of Eclipse (like Ctrl+Click to jump to another file)
It dedicated for the business domains I mentioned and there is side product specific for Fraud, Predicitive analytics and so on...

Tibco Business Events - uses CEP (Complex Event Processing) but there is no business user interface at all.

Hope it helps.
To sum up, if you want the best approach for non technical user to author rules then JRules. If you have low budget then JBoss rules.